# in CSS, I can't figure out how to add "content" to "first-line" or "first-letter"

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
ul.myList {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;


&:first-line {
  color: $blue;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 100%
}
```

I used "first-line" to make the color of the first line blue. What I want to do is to add content. I tried this by using

```
content: "+";
```

I also tried using a `li` before, and by using `first-letter`. However using `first-letter`, replicates the "+" to all the elements of the list. So my interface would look like this:

```
+ parent
  + child
  + child
```

I simply want this:

```
+ parent (blue color)
child
child
child
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You don't change the content of the first line or letter. What you might want to do is use [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to *add* content.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: You should start with proper HTML. For a parent-child structure, you should be using nested UL/LI to begin with. And don't confuse "line" with a list item or child element.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `content` property with just anything (go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)), you have to use it with either the `::before` or the `::after` pseudo-element; in your case, `::before` (Obviously, because you want to insert the "+" before the text, not after it).

Here is how you do it:

```css
p::first-line {
color: blue;
text-align: left;
font-size: 100%
}

p::before {
content: "+";
}
```

```html
<p>
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
My name is Jon Snow and I know nothing.
</p>

<br>

<p>
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
</p>
```

See [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before) article as well.